# SQL Update from Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update table1 
set month =  x

    select FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMM yyyy') x
    from table1 
    where currenmonth >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
     and currentmonth < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'x'

Not sure why I get this error. Need help. Thanks.

Comment: ??  [SQL Update Month base on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803477/sql-update-month-base-on-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't even a correct query.

Check this example (from https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/):

```
UPDATE
  books
SET
  books.primary_author = authors.name
FROM
  books
INNER JOIN
  authors
ON
  books.author_id = authors.id
WHERE
  books.title = 'The Hobbit'
```

So your query should be something like...

```
update table1
set month = FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMM yyyy')
from table1 
     where   
         currenmonth >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
         and currentmonth < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. But what if I wnat go back last 2 months. Can you help?

Comment: Then the where clause will be this: where currenmonth >= dateadd(month, -2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
         and currentmonth < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)

Answer (score 0):

This is  help full for you.

```
update table1 
set month = FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMM yyyy')
    from table1 as t
    where t.currenmonth >= dateadd(month, -1, 
    datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
     and t.currentmonth < datefromparts(year(getdate()), 
month(getdate()), 1)
```